# In Ruby, what is the best way to execute a local Linux command stored in a string?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, what is the simplest way to execute a local Linux command stored in a string while catching any potential exceptions that are thrown and logging the output of the Linux command and any thrown errors to a common log file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same question before, and "[Process management](http://whynotwiki.com/Ruby_/_Process_management)" answered all my needs.

If you don't want to separate the error from normal output just use `popen`:

```
output = IO.popen("other_program", "w+") do |pipe|
  pipe.puts "here, have some input"
  pipe.close_write
  pipe.read
end
```

but if you do want to, use `popen3`:

```
Open3.popen3('nroff -man') { |stdin, stdout, stderr| ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

look at [IO.popen](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M002242)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute `ls -a`:

```
%x[ls -a]
```

Comment: `%x(ls -a)` is sufficient. You don't (and probably shouldn't) enclose the command and parameter inside `'`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use to see whether a process is active:

```
systemOutput=`ps -A | grep #{process_to_look_for}`
if systemOutput.include? process_to_look_for
  puts "#{process_to_look_for} is already running"
  exit
end
```